# How to classify li tags when we want it 2 times

Tags: html, css

I wanted to use `li` tags 2 times first time I used class with `li` tag

```
<ul *class="2"*>
<li *class="!"*><.......jpg" width="280" height="280" \></li>
<li class="!"><img src="......jpg" width="280" height="280" \></li>
```

And 2nd time...
I DID THIS

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="........html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">SONGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">GAMES</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href=".........html">GALLERY</a></li>
</ul>
```

MY CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0066ff;
}
```

I don't know why they are overlapping??Please tell me if anything wrong with the code above.

Comment: Because the `ul` has `position: fixed`

Comment: Just use some class name on `ul` and style it's `li` as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LGSon said, it's because you have

```
position: fixed
```

Defined on your ul tag css.

if you define one of them to use a class name instead (e.g.)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

ul.fixedHeader {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And your html would look something like this

```
<ul *class="2"*>
<li *class="!"*><.......jpg" width="280" height="280" \></li>
<li class="!"><img src="......jpg" width="280" height="280" \></li>
```

and

```
<ul class="fixedHeader">
  <li><a href="........html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">SONGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">GAMES</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href=".........html">GALLERY</a></li>
</ul>
```

You should be good to go. Further, I'm not sure what the asterisks are doing there... seems like invalid html to me.

Please comment if any part of this didn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you everyone.Now it is looking like I was thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with me

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0066ff;
}
```

```html
<ul *class="2"*>
<li *class="!"*><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/06/03/14/24/ladybug-796481_960_720.jpg"" width="280" height="280" \></li>
<li class="!"><img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/thailand.jpg" width="280" height="280" \></li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul>
  <li><a href="........html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">SONGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="........html">GAMES</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href=".........html">GALLERY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't post an answer, which is the same as the question, saying "it works for me", post a comment. Answers are suppose to solve a **none** working issue, not repeat one that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some class name on `ul` and style it's `li` as necessary

```css
.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.ul2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.ul2 li {
  float: left;
}
.ul2 li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ul2 li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
.ul2 li a.active {
  background-color: #0066ff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li>
    <img src="1.jpg " width="280 " height="280 " />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="2.jpg " width="280 " height="280 " />
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">SONGS</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">GAMES</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a class="active " href="#">GALLERY</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Shreya: Welcome, Happy to help!